# Iterate over multiple URLs with webdriverio

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, promise, async-await, webdriver-io

I have the following code. But this doesn't work, only creating one screenshot with the name `googleScreenshot-loop-0.png` which is white, not showing the webpage. How I can iterate through multiple URLs?

```
const path = require('path');
const webdriverio = require('webdriverio');

const options = {
    desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        chromeOptions: {
            args: ['--headless', '--disable-gpu', '--window-size=1920,1080'],
            binary: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe',
        },
    },
};
const client = webdriverio.remote(options);

const arr = ['https://domain1.com/', 'https://domain2.com/', 'https://domain3.com/'];

let i = 0;
Promise.all(arr).then((values) => {
    client
        .init()
        .url(values)
        .execute(function () {
            const styleElement = document.createElement('style');
            document.head.appendChild(styleElement);
            styleElement.sheet.insertRule('::-webkit-scrollbar { display: none; }');
        })
        .saveScreenshot(path.join(__dirname, `googleScreenshot-loop-${i++}.png`))
        .end();
}).catch((reason) => {
    console.log(reason);
});
```

A slightly modified example:

```
client.init().then(() => {
  return arr.map((value, i) => {
      return client
          .url(value)
          .execute(function () {
              const styleElement = document.createElement('style');
              document.head.appendChild(styleElement);
              styleElement.sheet.insertRule('::-webkit-scrollbar { display: none; }');
          })
          .saveScreenshot(path.join(__dirname, `googleScreenshot-loop-${i++}.png`))
  });
}).then((arrPromise) => {
  return Promise.all(arrPromise);
}).then(() => {
  return client.end();
}).catch((reason) => {
  console.log(reason);
});
```

This one creating 3 images, but only the first wbesite shown on all of the images.

**Update**

This one seems to work:

```
const arr = ['https://domain1.com/', 'https://domain2.com/', 'https://domain3.com/'];

const init = async (array) => {
    await client.init();

    let i = 0;
    for (const value of array) {
        await client.url(value);
        await client.execute(() => {
            const styleElement = document.createElement('style');
            document.head.appendChild(styleElement);
            styleElement.sheet.insertRule('::-webkit-scrollbar { display: none; }');
        });
        await client.saveScreenshot(path.join(__dirname, `googleScreenshot-loop-${i}.png`));

        i += 1;
    }

    return client.end();
};

init(arr);
```

Comment: Any console errors ?

Comment: I dont think screenshots will be taken for --headless

Comment: Do yourself a favor and take a look at the **[WDIO test-runner](http://webdriver.io/guide/testrunner/gettingstarted.html)**. It will make your tests easier to read and you can still use the same asynchronous approach. As it stands your tests are hard to read, not modular, hard to extend and by all means, not scalable.